# ModelForms and ForeignKeys

Tags: django, django-forms

I got the following models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ProjectParticipation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

class Receipt(models.Model):
    project_participation = models.ForeignKey(ProjectParticipation)
```

Furthermore I have the following CreateView:

```
class ReceiptCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = ReceiptForm
    model = Receipt
    action = 'created'
```

I now want a dropdown menu where the User can choose the project, the new receipt should be for. The user should only see the project he is assigned to.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The simply answer is just create a [model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) read the docs, this is fundamental.

You may also want to look at [related names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), that way you can get the reverse on the FK.

```
class ProjectParticipation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='ProjectParticipation')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using a ModelChoiceField:

```
class ProjectModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.project

class ReceiptForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReceiptForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['project_participation'] = ProjectModelChoiceField(queryset= ProjectParticipation.objects)
class Meta:
    model = Receipt
```

And then in the CreateView:

```
class ReceiptCreateView(...)
    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super(ReceiptCreateView, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['project_participation'].queryset = ProjectParticipation.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return form
```

Is there a solution to filter the query set directly in the ModelForm?